# Potential Issues with Red Edge Inflection Point (REIP) Output from Sentinel-2 Images

Tags: google-earth-engine

I created a REIP raster on Google Earth Engine and I have results that seem questionable. REIP is calculated to determine vegetation health, and I seem to have some of the highest values in water and on impervious surfaces (pavement). The formula is as follows:

[image]

And the formula I used in google earth engine is below:

```
var reip = function(img){
  return img.expression('700 + 40*((B4+B7)/2 - B5)/(B6 - B5)', {
    'B4': img.select(['B4']),
    'B7': img.select(['B7']), 
    'B6': img.select(['B6']),
    'B5': img.select(['B5']),
   }).rename('REIP');
```

And I am getting results like this below (greens are water and impervious surfaces (not all impervious surfaces just some areas).

[image]

[image]

Are these results expected for a REIP output or was there an issue with the way I calculated it in GEE?

Comment: You didn't provide a complete script, so it's hard to tell if you made any mistake. I would verify that you re-scaled the values from `0-10,000` to `0-1`.